# Error running .net 4 application in xp

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.0, windows-xp

I am getting the following error when I try to run my .NET 4 application in Windows XP

```
event type clr20r3
p1 transfersectorapp.exe
p2 1.0.0.0
p3 51200779
p4 presentationcore
p5 4.0.0.0
p6 4ba1f865
p7 1a53
p8 1d
p9 system.io.filenotfoundexception
```

I don't know why this is happening, even though I have my prerequisites installed (.net 4 client profile on the xp machine). The applications runs fine on windows 7. Let me know if you need any extra information

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what's happening ..it's stating `System.IO.FileNotFountException` question is ..what file is it stating that it can't file ..is this this a 2.0/3.5 .DLL.. also recompile the project and set the project to run as 3.5 and see if it fixes the issue..if it does that means you need to find the updated version of the .DLL you are trying to reference..

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess without the app code, but seems that the app is trying to read a file and is not finding it, either by not having correct permissions set or by the file not existing at all

Comment: How do I go about debugging this error? I am trying to run it in .net 3.5, but in the meantime is  there a way to understand this problem?

Comment: The application tries to read a smartcard, the smartcard sdks are in  C++, and I have written an wrapper to be used in C#. So the error happens when I try to perform any actions on the card. My guess is the assembly reference to the interop may be missing, is there way to debug this error?

Comment: I added an unhandled exception to my program, and it seems like the DLL (wrapper) is missing, I don't understand why this is not referenced, though it is copied to the output folder. I am currently using the release folder for testing